# How can I open RDP using Ansible?

Tags: linux, windows, ansible, rdp

I am working on automating the installation of a custom, in-house software using Ansible on a windows host. During the automation process I have found that one of the msi installers is broken and as a result have to be run interactively on the machine.

I want to trigger the process to run interactively on the machine so the installation completes properly.

The challenge is to open a RDP session from Linux to the windows host to enable this to happen. I am using WSL.

I would like to keep the number of additional dependencies to a minimum.

Comment: So, do I understand correctly that you are expecting ansible to connect over RDP and start clicking on things like it was Selenium or something? Because that's not a thing. If it's an in-house .msi, then you're asking the wrong group of people for a fix

Comment: Nope. Looking for a way to open a RDP session and leave it in a disconnected state which will then enable me trigger PowerShell script interactively as that user. I agree that the best way to get this fixed is to work with the devs but they are unable to allocate time at this moment.